# what data type to use when to store unix time stamps in a Hive table

Tags: hive, unix-timestamp, hiveql

Sample of time stamps I'm working with: 
 - 874833878 
 - 887736532
 - 879196566
 - 892430094
do I just store them as (my_date **TIMESTAMP**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hive [date UDFs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) expect UNIX timestamps in the `BIGINT` data type, so using that for your field would be most compatible.